# Funds not received in wallet

Tags: transactions

I have requested funds sent to my Electrum Wallet receiving address, but have not received over a week now. According to the Blockchain ledger the funds are shown as "Unspent", help needed

Answer (score -1):

If you used the receive tab and created a payment request but did not give that request to anybody, you won't magically receive funds. You cannot just "request funds" and expect Bitcoin to be magically sent to your wallet; that is not how Bitcoin works, it is not something that is magically given out for free.

If you gave someone an address to send to or sent them the payment request but that person still has not sent you money, then you should contact them and ask them why they did not send you funds yet.

If the sender has sent you the funds but you do not see the transaction in your wallet nor do you see it on a blockchain explorer, then the transaction has not confirmed and has likely been dropped from the network due to low transaction fees. If you do see it on a block explorer and it is unconfirmed, then wait for it to confirm or to drop from the network (i.e. you don't see it on block explorers). If the transaction cannot be found on block explorers, ask the person who sent you the Bitcoin to send the Bitcoin again but include a higher transaction fee. Or have them rebroadcast their transaction.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I should have been more specific. I opened the receive tab, which automatically generated a receive address. I provided that address to the sender. They confirmed it was sent. The receiving address appeared in the Blockchain ledger, which matched the address in my Electrum wallet provided to the sender. It currently shows as "Unspent" on the Blockchain ledger. Any assistance is appreciated. – Neil 31 secs ago   edit

Comment: I should also mention, the receiving address is still shown in my wallet and is exactly what is indicated in the Blockchain ledger. Would this indicate and confirm that the sender has in fact sent the funds? Is it possible the fees attached by the sender were so minimal, thus creating the delay? Again, thank for any help you can provide me.

Comment: Andrew, not sure what block explorer is. I see the transaction on Blockchain.info/address. Is this the same as to what you are referring to? Is it dangerous for me to provide the link so you may be able to verify what I see and interpret it correctly? Sorry I am not too savy with Bitcoin or my Electrum wallet. In other words am I at risk to giving out the receiving address used. Would someone be able to interfere with this transaction?

Comment: Andrew, my apologies, I do see the transaction on https://blockexplorer.com/address/1etFi9F46qnfZobJfN69hHchCS7G3ivRu. It appears confirmed, with a fee of 0.00408715BTC = $17.55. Should this fee amount be sufficient? Perhaps the issue is with my Electrum wallet not updating or similar problem. How can I resolve this?

Comment: The transaction is confirmed which means that it is in the blockchain. Do you not see the transaction in your wallet?

Comment: Yes sir, I did. All good now. I noticed when I open my Electrum wallet today, it was bouncing between servers, all of a sudden the transaction appeared. I think Electrum server was down for a while, hence the 9 day delay. With the fee above at $17.55, would that still cause this delay? Thanks again Andrew for responding, your the only one that did.

Comment: FWIW, I now refuse to even use block explorer at all or for anything, because {opinion self-censored to prevent depreciation of comment}. Meanwhile, their opinions are published.